# Data retention in timescaledb

Tags: postgresql, rrdtool, timescaledb

Trying to wrap my head around timescaledb, but my google-fu is failing me.  Most likely because I'm not searching for the correct term.

With RRD tool, old data can be stored as averages, reducing the amount of data being stored.

I can't seem to find out how to do this with timescaledb.  I'd like 5 minute resolution for 90 days, but after that, it's pointless to keep all those data points, and I'd like to reduce it to 30 or 60 minute averages for a couple years, then maybe daily averages after that.

Is this something that I can set in the database itself, or is this something I would have to implement in a housekeeping job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had the exact same question half a year ago.

The term "Data Retention" is also used by the timescaledb team. It is currently implemented using `drop_chunks` policies (see [their doc here](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/data-retention)). It's a Enterprise feature but IMHO not (yet) as useful as it could/should be (and it surely does not do what you are looking for).

Let me explain: probably the easiest approach for down-sampling your data are Continuous Aggregates ([their doc here](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/continuous-aggregates)). You can quite easily aggregate virtually any numeric value to whatever resolution you desire. However, Continuous Aggregates will be affected by the deletions of the `drop_chunks`, too. Your data is gone.

One workaround would be to create other Hypertables instead. Then, create your own background workers copying the data from the original, hi-res table to these new lo-res Hypertables.
For housekeeping, either use the Data Retention Enterprise feature or create your own background workers.

Comment: Note: timescale just got an update where these issues have been addressed [see their blog](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/timescaledb-1-6-data-retention-policies-for-continuous-aggregates/?utm_source=timescale-january-2020&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=newsletter&utm_content=featured-announcement-blog&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-8itX63H5WCmEq5Go61sqwdOt6vEK6Fn4aiUvPW_0etLVqlul7MMj6JijNYBaa-_-5C6VagOdy2vpPrx99TM5H2EaV92g&_hsmi=82081018).